# Problemas con relacion Muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel

tengo dos relaciones muchos a muchos, una tabla usuarios y otra roles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo en la base de datos un usuario con 3 roles cargados, pero al momento de buscar, solo me trae 1 role.

```
class RoleModel extends BaseModel {

protected $table = 'role';
protected $fillable = ['role'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function usuarios() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Moltareas\Usuario\UsuarioModel', 'role_x_usuario',  'idUsuario','idRole')
                    ->withTimestamps();
}
}

class UsuarioModel extends Authenticatable {

use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'usuario';
protected $fillable = [ 'nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'password', 'idRole'];
protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Moltareas\Role\RoleModel', 'role_x_usuario', 'idRole', 'idUsuario')
                    ->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

Y al momento de traer los roles de usuario hago:

```
introducir el código aquí

$user = Moltareas\Usuario\UsuarioModel::get();

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    var_dump($role);
}
```

Y esto solamente me muestra que el usuario solo tiene 1 role, cuando en realidad tiene 3 cargados.

Si hago un dd($role) dentro del foreach, me muestra esto

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
"id" => 1
"role" => "ADMINISTRADOR"
"deleted_at" => null
"created_at" => "2016-10-07 09:57:27"
"updated_at" => "2016-10-07 09:57:27"
]
```

Comment: Tenes una tabla pivote? o como implementaste? para q tenes idRole en usuario?

Comment: podes mostrar un dd del role dentro del foreach?

Comment: probaste sacarle los parametros extras a belogsToMany? yo implente algo parecido hace poco pero con tags y articulos y segui la documentacion y ningun problema. pero puse a que modelo se relacionaba. En tu caso 'Moltareas\Role\RoleModel'

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Si le saco los parametros extras no anda, porque laravel espera un id_algo... y yo uso idRole

Comment: no abras nuevas respuestas. edita el primer post

Comment: Probé lo que me dijiste y tampoco, es rarisimo. Cuando encuentre la solución la publicare

Comment: Haz un **dd( $user )** para ver si los datos están ahí. En cuyo caso el error no es de como manejas la relación.

Comment: hay una libreria que se llama spatie: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission me permiter administra permiso desde la vista hasta el route

Answer (score 1):

Intenta hacer esta consulta y verifica que si te da los resultados.

```
SELECT * FROM role_x_usuario WHERE idUsuario = [ID DEL USUARIO]
```

Creo que el problema es que tienes invertido los campos

```
class UsuarioModel extends Authenticatable {

    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'usuario';
    protected $fillable = [ 'nombre', 'apellido', 'email', 'password', 'idRole'];
    protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function roles() {
    // Acá es donde esta invertido los campos
        return $this->belongsToMany('Moltareas\Role\RoleModel', 'role_x_usuario', 'idUsuario', 'idRole')
                        ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo muy parecido en la documentación de laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: te recomiendo no borrar la primer respuesta y después publicar otra mas en la misma pregunta que tratas de ayudar, basta con que a la primera respuesta que diste le des en editar y hagas los cambios necesarios

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que todo esta correctamente cargado me parece que el problema debe estar en como mostras

```
$users = Moltareas\Usuario\UsuarioModel::orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
$users->each(function($users){
        $users->roles;
    })
dd($users);
```

En este each le agrega a cada user los roles con los que se relaciona